# What's the lightest way to set up a 301 permanent redirect?

Tags: node.js, redirect

I have to set up a web server whose sole function is to redirect all traffic from http://example.com to http://www.example.com. I set up a nodejs server that does the following:

`var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(301, {'Location': 'http://www.doskara.com'});
  response.end();
}).listen(80);`

I was wondering if there were any security issues that I needed to be aware of, or if there are any other options that are simpler to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably install Nginx and set that up to forward all requests to the new site. Rolling your own solution like you've done here strikes me as a bad idea, since it's not likely to be as robust as one of the common production web servers. Nginx is pretty straightforward to configure, and it's meant to be very fast and lightweight.

I think something like this would do the trick:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite ^/(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```